Eigenvalues of likelihood ratio
Consider the following hypothesis testing problem:
Under $H_0$: $(X,Y) \sim N(0,1)\times N(0,1)$, i.e. $X$ and $Y$ are independent standard normal.
Under $H_1$: $(X,Y) \sim N\left(\begin{pmatrix}
 0\\0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
  1& \rho\\
 \rho &1
\end{pmatrix}\right)$, i.e. they are normal distribution with correlation coefficient $\rho$.
Let $Q$ denote the density of $N(0,1)$, then the joint density of $(X,Y)$ under $H_0$ is $Q(x)Q(y)$. Let $P(x,y)$ denote the joint density of $(X,Y)$ under $H_1$. Then $L(x,y)= \frac{P(x,y)}{Q(x)Q(y)}$ is the likelihood ratio.
For functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, lets define inner product induced by $Q$ as $<f,g> = \mathbb{E}_{(X,Y)\sim N(0,1)\times N(0,1)} f(X,Y)g(X,Y)$. Then we know that $L(x,y)$ is diagonalizable in this inner product space and can be written as
$$L(x,y) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \lambda_k \phi_k(x)\phi_k(y)$$
where $\lambda_k$'s are the eigenvalues of $L$ (in this particular example $\lambda_k = \rho^k$) and $\phi_k$'s is a set of orthonomal basis (in this particular example, $\phi_k$ is Hermite polynomial multiplied by constant).
My question is if we conduct a transform on the distribution of $X$ and $Y$, will the eigenvalues of likelihood ratio change or not?
To be specific, Let $F$ denote the CDF of $N(0,1)$. Then $F(X)$ follows $U(0,1)$ (uniform distribution on $(0,1)$). After this transformation, we have those two new hypotheses:
Under $H_0$: $(F(X),F(Y)) \sim U(0,1)\times U(0,1)$. Here we use $\tilde Q(x) \tilde Q(y)$ denote the new joint density.
Under $H_1$: $(F(X),F(Y))$ follows a new distribution where we use $\tilde P(x,y)$ to denote the new density.
Then $\tilde L(x,y) =\frac{\tilde P(x,y)}{\tilde Q(x)\tilde Q(y)}$ is the new likelihood ratio after transformation.
For functions $f,g : (0,1)\times (0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$, we define the new inner product as $\langle f,g \rangle = \mathbb{E}_{(X,Y)\sim U(0,1)\times U(0,1)} f(X,Y)g(X,Y)$.
Then $\tilde L$ also has an decomposition in this inner product space, as
$$\tilde L(x,y) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \tilde \lambda_k \tilde \phi_k(x)\tilde \phi_k(y)$$.
Here we must have $\phi_k \neq \tilde \phi_k$ becasue they are orthonormal basis on different spaces. But do we have $\lambda_k = \tilde \lambda_k$?
Sorry about the long description. Let me know if there is any thing needs clarification.

This question is asking whether the eigenvalue of likelihood ratio is unchanged under the probability integral transform (transfer a random variable to uniform distribution). If it is the case, we my assume the distribution under the $H_0$ to be independent uniform to simplify the setting.
